# How to optimize the following shell command to get the ouput real quick?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need to check the count for a particular ID in the logs, for the last 24 hrs in   Unix server. Right now, I'm using the following command

```
find -type f -newermt "aug 27, 2018 02:30" ! -newermt "aug 28, 2018 02:30" ! -exec grep -r 'commandType\": \"PATTERN' {} \;|wc -l
```

Since, data in the logs are huge, the above command takes more than 1 hour to give the output. Is there anyway to optimize the above command to get the output real quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the *first* thing to do would be to find out where the time is being spent. Is it the `find` or the `grep`. You can establish the cost of the `find` by just running:

```
time find -type f -newermt "aug 27, 2018 02:30" ! -newermt "aug 28, 2018 02:30" -exec true \;
```

Then, if it's the `grep` taking up all the time, there are a couple of possibilities:

1. Batch up the `files` using `xargs` to run a single `grep` over much larger groups of files. This will generally only help if there are a large *number* of files which may or may not be the case.
2. Work out how to optimise the pattern you're searching for. I'm presuming here that the pattern you've provided is a generic one so we can't really help with that unless we know exactly what it is. One possibility (if your ID is a fixed string) is to use `grep -F` instead of `grep` since it may be optimised for that use case. Oh, and by the way, the `-r` is probably irrelevant since you're only processing files anyway - no need to recurse.

Comment: I used "xargs" instead of "exec", the run time reduced from 50 min to 15 min. Thanks paxdiablo.